# In excel sheet if someone tries to manipulate my standard data,color of the particular cell to be changed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-manipulation

I have 3 columns in my Excel "Priority","Availability" and "Turn around Time"
If i enter under Priority column as "High" it automatically fills the rest of columns ("Availaibility" as 24X7 and "Turn around time" as 4 hours) based on the predefined standards and formula.BUt if some one manipulates the data for example change "Availaibility" from 4 hours to 6 hours or other value different than standard, i want to change the cell color to Red.Thanks in advance for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem if a cell formula is overwritten in this way.  You will somehow need to replace the formula.  How about not allowing the formula to be changed in the first place?

Assuming the following layout and the cell formula `=IF(B3="High","4 hours","")` is in cell D3:

[image]

then how about something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "$D$3" Then
            If Not (Range("B3").Value = "High" And Range("D3").Value = "4 hours") Then
                qm = Chr(34)
                Range("D3").Formula = "=IF(B3=" & qm & "High" & qm & "," & qm & "4 hours" & qm & "," & qm & qm & ")"
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

This code should be placed in the Sheet module in question and not a standard module.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO OP COMMENT**

Conditional formatting is, as its name suggests, concerned with formatting and not with the contents of cells.  If you accept the premise of not allowing the formula to be overwritten then you may consider 'Lock'ing that particular cell on the worksheet.  In this way the user will not be able to modify the cell or its contents.

For more info have a look at [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-HA010342979.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for solution..i am also interested to know if there is some other way in the excel sheet(for ex:by using formula or conditional formatting) instead of writing this code?

Comment: OK Sai thanks.  If this answers your requirement please mark as Answer in order to close-off this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)` event from sheet you want to evaluate.
Example: Change the text color to red if someone modifies the value of the cell J2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "$J$2" Then
            Range("J2").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
End Sub
```

With Conditional Formatting:

```
Assuming the cell where you want to apply conditional formatting is: B2.

1.Select the cell or cells where you want to apply conditional formatting.
2.Then, click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule. 
3.In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, click Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
4.Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula: =AND($B$2<>"24x7",$B$2 <>"20x7")
The formula uses the AND function to see if the cell B2 is different from the common values: "24x7", "20x7",... [You can keep adding more values separated by commas in the AND function]
 If so, the cells are formatted. 
5.Click Format.
6.In the Color box, select Red. In the Font Style box, select Bold.
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions..instead of writing a code do you also have a formula or a way in conditional formatting to do this..@jose